# How do you show a phrase or sentence in full screen?

Tags: accessibility, google-translate

Previously there was a menu option in Google Translate to show the translated text in full screen so it's easy to read from a distance. You could also use english as the visibility was the main feature useful in like a noisy nightclub or if one was temporarily or permanently mute.

However that feature in the latest update has disappeared.

I tried internet searching for "full screen" google translate for tens of minutes but couldn't find any answers.

What's the easiest way now to show large text, preferably though not necessarily using pre installed apps (such as Google translate) for availability?

See [screen cast recording](https://youtu.be/E0Kdk3r3hfM?t=90) for further details.

Comment: Could you clarify if the question is about "text translation" (as per the tags) or "showing text in full screen" (as per the title)?

Comment: Removed "translate" tag. Google translate was where I first discovered this feature in a convenient format but it is not necessary to use this app, just has to be easily available on android phones.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're likely looking for a [signboard](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Signboard&c=apps) app.  Just be warned, I haven't vetted any of these myself, so if you're wary of malicious apps (becoming more prevalent these days despite Google's mitigation efforts) you'll want to take your own precautions and research before settling on one.  For additional features such as preventing touch, etc., you may want to search for "kiosk" apps instead.